# upload a image and insert directly into CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, ckeditor

I'd like to create the same kind of function tumblr has for uploading images and then inserting them directly into the WYSIWYG editor.

I was planning on using uploadify to upload the image, then I am not sure of the method for inserting into the CKEditor.

Has anyone done anything similar or know of a plugin that could do this? Ideally I'd like it to insert the image wherever the text cursor was last placed.

[Upload an image and directly insert it into a text area http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/06217dcebb.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/06217dcebb.png)

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CKEDITOR.instances['instanceName'].insertHtml('<img src="your image">');
```

Comment: I'm using the latest version of CKeditor and get: CKEDITOR.instances.myinstanceName.insertHTML is not a function

Comment: my fault, the new function is insertHtml (watch caps!). This inserts the html tag as text, is it possible to render the image in the CKEditor as well?

Comment: fixed that as well... you have to use real html tags, not the &lt; and &gt; symbols. Thanks for your help here!

Answer (score 11):

Correct is:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['instanceName'].insertHtml('<img src="your image"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dropzone as the image uploader. I've added a button below each image such that when it's clicked an image is inserted at the cursor position in CKEditor. Please see the example below:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    // Hookup image insert button
    file.previewElement.querySelector('.insert').onclick = function() {
        var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<img src="' + $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/api/files/' + file.id + '?filter=image"/>');
        CKEDITOR.instances.body.insertElement(element);
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using nice plugin for CKeditor http://www.ckuploader.com

Comment: I looked at the FAQ for the "Uploader plugin for CKEditor" [link](http://www.ckuploader.com/faq) and it says "Uploader requires a HTTP server with support for PHP5 (coding language)".  This could be a limiting factor.

Comment: It also requires mootools.  I'm looking into https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload